# Why does gorm Where() and Debug().Where() execute differently

Tags: go, go-gorm

Here is the simplified code:

```
conn, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})tb := conn.Table("test1")
tmp := []testdb{}

tb.Where("tid=?", "1").Find(&tmp)
//This line of code executes the statement:
//select * from test1 where tid=1
//tb.Debug.Where("tid=?", "1").Find(&tmp) //print same statement

tb.Where("tid=?", "2").Find(&tmp)
//this line excutes select * from test1 where tid=1 and tid=2

//tb.Debug.Where("tid=?", "1").Find(&tmp) 
//executes:select * from test1 where tid=2
```

I don't understand why two Where() become  **"tid=1 and tid=2"**, and why Debug() is normal.thanks for the hand!

Comment: u have only one tmp, if &tmp.tid=1->sql(where tid=1), and Where("tid=?", "2") ->sql("tid=1 and tid=2"), you should new three tmp

Comment: thanks for help.  I create new tmp2,and run this line:-> tb.Where("tid=?", "2").Find(&tmp2)  .It still does ->("tid=1 and tid=2") . but i create new -> tb1 := conn.Table("test1") and run ,it working fine. thanks again!!